# Why underline does not shows up in dark mode?

Tags: html, css, underline, darkmode

I can't really understand why underline links does not shows up on dark mode (only on some browser on mobile).

The code is really simple:

```css
a {
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: solid 0.10em rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"> example </a>
```

In dark mode it works fine on every desktop browser.
On mobile it works fine with Chromium and Firefox. But on Brave, Bromite and Privacy Browser the underline links just diseapper (otherwise, on light mode they works fine).

The same issue is with other borders.

Firefox Browser with borders:
[image: Firefox Browser with borders]

Brave Browser without borders:
[image: Brave Browser without borders]

I can post the website link if it is ok.

Comment: Never heard of those browsers.  Does anyone actually use them?

Comment: The borders are still there if you look closley they are just verry dull

Comment: set `border-color:#ffffff;` as a fallback because of this  https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/issues/9332

Comment: @Viira that specific issue has been fixed and is closed so it's not relevant

Comment: ok then how about this? https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: @Viira I have tried with border-color: #fffff but unsuccesfully

Comment: ok I found out at least the reason even if I still have to figure out how to fix it. The problem is that these browsers evidently use the chrome: // flags "Force Dark Mode for Web Contents."

With this flag enabled I can reproduce the problem even on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the border is still existent in brave browser but that it is dull it is my best advice apply `filter:brighntnes(50%)` to the  element

**`CSS` reset code:**

```css
.element { 
 -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: solid 0.10em rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;

  border:5px solid #fff;
}
.element:before {
  filter:brightness(50%);
}
.element > * {
  filter:brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
    <a href="element"> example </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `rgba` is [not supported by some browsers](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/). I recommend you to add a fallback css with `rgb` colors. Or try with hex colors You can convert [here](https://simplecss.eu/rgbatohex.html).

After adding the fallback you're code should be looking like this.

```css
a {
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-bottom-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: solid 0.10em rgb(255, 255, 255); /*fallback here*/
  border-bottom: solid 0.10em rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"> example </a>
```

Comment: Nope, adding RGB colors seems have no effects.